# Please help me with my comment sections sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments

OK guys, I am in need of a little help here! Using PHP and mysql, I made a comment section that users can add comments to. First off, the page is based off of the ItemID and displays the correct item. When they add a comment, I take their username and the ItemID and put it in the comment table as comment.username and messageailmentID. So the page displays correctly, and the comment section works great, except that I cannot seem to get the SQL query right. I have tried many variations, with no luck. I want the comment that anyone posts under the pages ItemID to show only those comments under that ItemID (specifically messageailmentID).

MY query ranges, but here is the one I have at the moment:

```
SELECT `comment`.messageID, `comment`.message, `comment`.username, `comment`.messageailmentID, Items.ItemID
FROM `comment`, Items
WHERE varItemID = `comment`.messageailmentID
```

(Using dreamweaver, the varItemID is basically $_GET['Items.ItemID'])

EDIT: As an example, The user clicks an item which takes them to the itemdetails.php?ItemID=8. When they leave a comment, it will add Items.ItemID into comment.messageailmentID.

The important part of the table columns are this:

Items: ItemID

comment: CommentID, message, comment.username, messageailmentID(which is the pages ItemID)

The varItemID isn't a column, but does $_GET['ItemID'], which may not even be needed in this query because it is done on another query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fetching all rows.

You should use:

- A `JOIN` clause to specify the relationship between the tables.
- A `WHERE` clause to specify which particular items you want to fetch.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    comment.messageID,
    comment.message,
    comment.username,
    comment.messageailmentID,
    Items.ItemID
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN comment
ON Items.ItemID = comment.messageailmentID
WHERE Items.ItemID = 42
```

Using a left join means that it will still return one row even if there are no comments. Use INNER JOIN if you don't want this.

Comment: Thank you for your lightning fast response. So I tried it this way, and I am getting an error saying that the left join ON varItemID is an unknown column. Any ideas?

Comment: @micker: Probably the column `varItemId` doesn't exist in your `Items` table. Please edit your question to include your table definitions, and if possible please also add a description of how an Item is related to a Comment in your database (i.e. which columns are used in the relationship).

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, hoping to clear it up a little. Yeah, the On Items.varItemID is a $_GET['ItemID'], and not a column. Sorry about that! But I still cannot seem to get the join to work properly. (I've read SQl queries for mere mortals, but those joins for some reason are tricky for me)

Comment: @micker: It's not clear why you need a join. Why can't you just query the comments table?

Comment: Well, I want the comments that people post to only show on the particular page. I don't want the comments for ItemID 6 to show for ItemID 8.

Comment: @micker: Yes, so as far as I can see you only need to read from the `comments` table. You just need to add an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Are you sure, because the ItemID is in the Items table. I'm honestly not sure how to do this. EDIT: True, it sort of is in the comment table as well, but as messageailmentID.

Comment: @micker: Yes, I'm fairly sure you don't need to join. The ItemId should be in both tables. Think about it... if it *isn't* in both table, how do you expect to join?

Comment: So is my problem that ItemID is not named the same in both tables?

Comment: Ok, well thanks a ton for all your help Mark! I really appreciate it! I'll keep working at it to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT comment.messageID, comment.message, comment.username, comment.messageailmentID, Items.ItemID

FROM comment, Items

WHERE Items.ItemID = comment.messageailmentID and Items.ItemID = ". $_GET['Items.ItemID']
```

Comment: Thank you for the response ray. However, I have done an identical query in the past, and again when you responded to my question, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me figure out my own stupidity! The query I use that works is this:

```
SELECT `comment`.messageID, `comment`.message, `comment`.username
     , `comment`.ItemID, Items.ItemID
  FROM Items 
 INNER JOIN `comment` 
    ON Items.ItemID = `comment`.ItemID
 WHERE Items.ItemID = varItemID
```

`varItemID` is a `$_GET['ItemID']` also.